# Изменить N-е совпадение символа в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

у меня есть строка:

```
"sample sample sample"
```

И мне нужно изменить, например, второе совпадение, чтобы на выходе получилось:

```
"sample hello sample"
```

Как заменить все три совпадения я знаю:

```
"sample sample sample".replace(/sample/g, "hello");
```

Но как ограничиться именно вторым?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вторым параметром у [replace()](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-methods#str-replace-reg-str-func) может быть функция:

```js
var count = 0;
var num = 2;
var str = 'sample sample sample';
str = str.replace(/sample/g, function(a) {
  ++count;
  if (count == num) {
    return 'hello';
  } else {
    return a;
  }
});
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Да я знал, думал есть альтернатива

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "sample sample sample";
var arr = str.split(' ');
var count = 0;
var i = 0;
for (; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == "sample") {
    count++
  }
  if (count == 2) { // в count записываем какое совпадение по счету нужно изменить
    arr[i] = "hello";
    break;
  }
}
str = arr.join(' ');
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

При крайне малом разнообразии структуры, можно использовать что-то вроде этого:

```js
console.log('sample sample sample'.replace(/((sample).*?)(\2)/, '$1hello'));
```